# VBA Set the range for a function using the value of a cell for the column number

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to Excel VBA. I need to set the column range of a many COUNTA functions with the value of corresponding cells. Each couple of matching cells has the inicial column number and the final column number for the range of each function. I tried doing this defining the value of the cell as a variable and then defining a variable as an Address with the value as the column number. 
Like this:

```
Dim T1Address As String
T1Start = Sheets(2).Range("AQ3").Value
T1End = Sheets(2).Range("AR3").Value
T1Address = Cells(11, T1Start).Address & ":" & Cells(11, T1End).Address
Range("AT3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('1st Sheet'!T1Address)"
```

The problem is that the function does not work, it just shows the value "1" regardless of the number of not empty cells in the range. I learned that the part of the columns could also be done assigning a name to the range of the Adress variable, so I found a way to do this, but it doesn't seem to work either.
Like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
    Name:="RangeT1", _
    RefersTo:="T1Address"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You are passing `T1Address` as literal instead of variable. Try this: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('1st Sheet'!" & T1Address & ")"`

Comment: spare the `Select` and `ActiveCell` , just use `Range("AT3").Formula = "=COUNTA('1st Sheet'!" & T1Address & ")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `T1Address` as literal instead of variable. Try this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('1st Sheet'!" & T1Address & ")"
```

[Shai Rado's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704528/vba-set-the-range-for-a-function-using-the-value-of-a-cell-for-the-column-number/41704700#comment70605066_41704528) is actually way better. 
You can ignore `Select` and `ActiveCell` and just use

```
Range("AT3").Formula = "=COUNTA('1st Sheet'!" & T1Address & ")"
```

Another issue I see is that you are trying to store the value of the cell `"AQ3"` in `T1Start` and the value of the cell `"AR3"` in `T1End`. Not sure if that is actually your intention, but I think you meant to get the column number of those addresses. If that is the case, replace this:

```
T1Start = Sheets(2).Range("AQ3").Value
T1End = Sheets(2).Range("AR3").Value
```

With this

```
T1Start = Sheets(2).Range("AQ3").Column
T1End = Sheets(2).Range("AR3").Column
```

**UPDATE:** As per your comment, you want to refer to the first Worksheet in the Workbook, regardless of how it is called. Here are the alternatives in my knowledge to accomplish it:

- `Sheets(1).name` - Considers both Chart Sheets and Worksheets
- `Worksheets(1).name` - Considers only worksheets
- `Sheet1.name` - uses the name of the worksheet (not to be mistaken with the title, which the user can change)
- `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).name` - Qualified to the workbook from where the code is being called, which means if the user has more than one workbook opened, this should still work

Please note that I'm using the `.name` property of the Worksheet, because I don't want to work with the entire object. 
When you say you tried

```
Range("AT3").Formula = "=COUNTA(Sheets(1)" & T1Address & ")"
```

you made the same mistake as before, because you are passing `Sheets(1)` as literal instead of the object itself (which would also actually be wrong). This is how you can do it:

```
Range("AT3").Formula = "=COUNTA('" & Sheets(1).name & "'!" & T1Address & ")"
```

A couple of things to notice here:

- I'm using `Sheets(1).name` value as a parameter, not as a literal (Compare the highlight colors of `Sheets(1)` in my code and in yours for visual reference)
- I have enclosed the parameter with `'` (single quote) because that is how Excel understands it
- I have also appended `!` after the name, because this is Excel's syntax

So in the end, supposing your worksheet is named "MyWorksheet" and `T1Address` contains "A1", the value of cell "AT3" should be `=COUNTA('MyWorksheet'!A1)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yes, the issue was solved with the change in T1Address. The part of the value of "AQ3" is actually what I meant, I needed to set the range of the column on the function with the value of that cell.
I put '1st Sheet' as an example for the name of the sheet, but actually I need to refer to the first sheet of the Workbook, regardless of the name. I tried with 
Range("AT3").Formula = "=COUNTA(Sheets(1)" & T1Address & ")"
but it doesn't work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by Setting a Range, and then retrieving the `Address` from it.

**Note**: If I'd have more data, like if `Sheets(2) and/or`'1st Sheet'` and/or where you want to place this formula are maybe overlapping (the same sheet).

Try the code below:

```
Dim T1Rng As Range

Set T1Rng = Range(Cells(11, Sheets(2).Range("AQ3").Column), Cells(11, Sheets(2).Range("AR3").Column))
Range("AT3").Formula = "=COUNTA('1st Sheet'!" & T1Rng.Address & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You say in a comment to one of the other answers that you don't want to count cells on sheet "1st Sheet", but instead want to count cells on whatever sheet currently appears first in the workbook.  If so, change your code from:

```
Range("AT3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('1st Sheet'!T1Address)"
```

to

```
Range("AT3").Formula = "=COUNTA('" & Worksheets(1).Name & "'!" & T1Address & ")"
```